# $scope.someFunc = function(){} becomes null in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, coffeescript, scope

I have this small Angular app. I want the scopes to have a function named by `someFunc` so that I can use it from any view. However, when I access it from my views, it becomes `null`, while variables such as `someVar` holds the contents as intended.

Using AngularJS Batarang, I can confirm that the $rootScope.someFunc is indeed `null`.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here?

`app.js.coffee`:

```
app = angular
  .module 'app'
  .run ($rootScope) ->
     $rootScope.someFunc = -> 'whatever'
  .controller 'default', ($scope) ->
     $scope.someVar = 'whatever'
```

`app.html`:

```
<html ng-app='app'>
  <head><script src='./app.js'><!-- assuming it's compiled from app.js.coffee --></head>
  <body ng-controller='default'>
    <p>$scope.someVar = {{someVar}}</p>
    <p>$rootScope.someFunc() = {{someFunc()}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? Even if it's a bad practice to use `$rootScope` as a global variable, all seems to be right here.

Comment: Should be working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/ahchurch/XZn6m/3/ - Send us a full fiddle to try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Blackhole and Andrew.

After some struggling, I found out that the functions assigned to `$rootScope` and `$scope` indeed do exist and accessible from views. There were two things that tricked me to believe they don't:

- AngularJS Batarang showed the functions in the model as `null`

[image: Batarang]

- `ng-click="someRootScopeFunc()"` outside any controller did not trigger the function nor did not raise any error.

I feel the latter strange, but it might be just my understanding of AngularJS is limited.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a classical forum, it's a Q/A forum :) So you shouldn't add your post to discuss with others, just to give the solution. However, you can edit you first post if you want to add some details :) Also, please provide us a JSFiddle of your complete code ;)